# Can't find kafka library in confluent repository

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am using confluent and according to the official document, I only have to configure below in pom.xml like this:

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>
        <!-- further repository entries here -->
</repositories>


<dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <!-- For CP 3.1.0 -->
            <version>0.10.1.0-cp1</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But seems kafka_2.11 with version 0.10.1.0-cp1 does not exits.
The website http://packages.confluent.io/maven/ cannot be reached too.
How can I get it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please show the output of running `mvn clean compile` when trying to use a Kafka library in code. Also, you'll want to update the version there to be your Kafka version. 3.1 is fairly old now

Answer (score 3):

I am using below maven dependancy its working fine for me :

```
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>connect-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.2.0-cp1</version>
   </dependency>



 <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <name>Confluent</name>
            <url>http://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
 </repository>
```

Hopefully this will help

Comment: There is no error message. Just the pom file showed red line, prompting that the dependency cannot be found.

Comment: I verified again thing work fine for me. So it seems the issue you are facing is something related to maven setup or pom issue. You can download the jar and directly point to that jar in pom.xml using tag <scope>system</scope>

Comment: thankyou. after hours of solutions, this one worked for me !